# JSP dynamic include and same method declaration

Tags: jsp, methods, include

I have on jsp page, which include dynamically other pages with `<jsp:include page="<%=jspFile%>" flush="true"/>`. The files, which should be included contains all the same function `show()`, how can I override the methods dynamically?
I need it becuase first I include the jsp, which contains some important checks and after it I want to use the function show, to get the content.

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: Is this a homework project or something? I'm asking this because the most weird requirements usually come from homework/test assignments. There are maybe ways (read: hacks) for this paricular one, but a complete redesign is better.

Comment: It is like a homework, but there aren't any reasons against a redesign, because I want to produce good stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had it resolved with a Servlet, which takes the role of the controller and use the jsp only as view.